# Can't modify RIP register on Windows with buffer overflow

Tags: windows, 64-bit, cpu, cpu-registers, buffer-overflow

So as a learning exercise I wanted to write a buffer overflow. However I ran into some problems which seem to be involved with the x64 architecture. I found the following [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402220/creating-a-buffer-overflow-on-windows-10) and was trying to recreate the steps.

The result being that I can overwrite EIP on 32 bit Windows but can't overwrite RIP in 64 bit Windows. I would like to know why I can't overwrite RIP on 64 bit Windows?

I found this page with manuals detailing the [Intel architecture](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) however I genuinely have no idea which of those manuals to read first, or if the answer will even be in those manuals it just looked like a good place to start.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct Buffers {
    char buffer1[6];
    char buffer2[6];
};

int main(int argc)
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;

    Buffers b = {};
    strcpy(b.buffer2, "Hello");
    cout << b.buffer2 << endl;

    strcpy(b.buffer1, input.c_str());

    cout << b.buffer2 << endl;
}
```

As an example if you supply a string of A's as input to the program when running in 32 bit mode (with things like /GS turned of in Visual Studio) you can overwrite EIP. However if you try and do this on the program when compiled for 64 bit you RIP does not get filled with A's.

Comment: One note is that modern compilers and operating systems have various [safeguards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection), such as stack canaries, that would prevent a naive buffer overflow attack from working.  If you want to do this as an exercise, you'll probably have to disable those safeguards.

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite RIP"?  Do you mean overwriting the return address on the stack, or having the machine actually try to return to the new address?  What tests did you do to conclude that it isn't happening?  What are you giving your program as input, and how did you choose it?

Comment: I attached the program to X64dbg and tried providing a string of A's as the input. When compiled for 32 bit you can have the instruction pointer (EIP register) in the debugger read 41414141 however this doesn't happen when compiled for 64 bit.